# Is it right to say "I have started to watch" or better to say "I have been watching"?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

Here are my sentences.

> I have been watching football since 2010 World Cup, and I liked players like Drogba, Lampard, and after World Cup, I **have started** to watch Premier League.

Is it right to say "I have started to watch" or better to say "I have been watching" in this context?

Comment: I 'd change "I have started to watch" into I started watching or I started to watch after the World Cup, because you state a moment in the past : after the world cup, so use past simple. The first sentence is correct.

Comment: @anouk is it right to say i **have not been reading** any books for 3 month?

Comment: If you haven't read any books for 3 months, use present perfect simple, because you haven't read any. If I were to say to you : "You have been reading books for 3 months now, I want you to stop because we need to paint the house", you could reply: "I haven't been reading for 3 months, only 6 weeks", for example.

Answer (score 0):

I would say

> I have been watching football since *the* 2010 World Cup and I *like* players like Drogba *and* Lampard. After World Cup I *started* to watch Premier League.

Saying *have started* doesn't seem right in this situation because of the *After World Cup* it is fine to say *I have started to watch...* or *I have started watching* on their own.

Answer (score 0):

“I have been watching” is good. An alternative would be “I started watching football during the 2010 World Cup”.